# How does hibernateTemplate do save operation?

Tags: java, hibernate, junit

When I do JUnit tests, `save(new TCGroup())` inserts but  `save(list.get(i))` doesn't insert.

Based on my code, why is that?

```
@Before
public void before() throws Exception {
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        TCGroup tcGroup = new TCGroup();
        tcGroup.setGroupName("GROUP"+i);
        lists.add(tcGroup);
    }
    tcGroupDao.saveList(lists);
} 
@Test
@Transactional
@Rollback(true)
public void testSave() throws Exception {
    assertEquals(10L,tcGroupDao.queryForObject("select count(*) from TCGroup",null));
    tcGroupDao.save(lists.get(0));
    assertEquals(11L,tcGroupDao.queryForObject("select count(*) from TCGroup",null));
    TCGroup tcGroup = new TCGroup();
    tcGroup.setGroupName("GroupAdd");
    tcGroupDao.save(tcGroup);
    assertEquals(11L,tcGroupDao.queryForObject("select count(*) from TCGroup",null));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tcGroupDao.save(lists.get(0))` doesn't add anything to the database, because `lists.get(0)` is already in the database. It was added during the executon of `before()`.